# What to do if someone has answered my question as a comment but not posted an answer?

Tags: support, comments, accepted-answer

For example, [my question on math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3455787/574752) got answered by somebody in the comments. Since you can't accept comments, what should I do now?

Comment: Be glad you got an answer to something that was bothering you and move on.